# push notification is not working iphone4 and in iphone3

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I developed a application which uses push notification,it was working fine but when today i updated and when i run the application ,app is not able to get device token,both delegates methods are not called .but when i see the notification in settings of iphone ,i find my app as registered for notification ,how can i fix this problem any help?

Comment: Please be more clear.. How do you get the device token? In which method etc. This way it is very difficult for us to solve your problem...

Comment: i used didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: method of applications delegate but this time neither this method is called nor didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError method is called .

Comment: ur device probably unlocked device,so may be thats may be the reason

Comment: ya its unlock but i was receiving notification previously,but one thing I  am using xcode 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Unlocked iPhones have many problems with Push Notifications. Check the web, there are some work arounds you can do to get it working. Strange that it worked before, but now it isn't.. The methods you spoke about are the correct methods and should be fired when launching the app...

You can try to kill the app from the multitasking. Maybe that's the case the methods aren't called...